# SQL Consolidating Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to consolidate some rows when I query data from SQL Server. The timestamp seems to give me an issue for not being able to consolidate. My `invoiceqty` column needs to be a sum while all other columns can be consolidated. I think I may need to change the timestamp to `MMDDYYYY`, however since I'm not aggregating the date column, I am forced to list it under `GROUP BY`. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
I am trying to sum up the invoiceQTY rows that have similar container number and skus

[image]

```
WITH did AS
( 
    SELECT
        [did].[CustomerLotReference] AS Container,
        [did].[WarehouseSku] AS warehouessku,
        SUM([did].[InvoicedQty]) AS invoiceqty,
        [did].[CreateDate]
    FROM 
        [server].[dbo].[table] AS did
    WHERE 
        [did].[table] = 'customer'
    GROUP BY 
        [did].[CustomerLotReference],
        [did].[WarehouseSku],
        [did].[CreateDate]  
), so AS 
(
    SELECT
        [so].[OrderGroup] AS container,
        [so].OtherReferenceFour AS warehousesku,
        SUM([so].[QtyOrdered]) AS AllocatedQty
    FROM
        [server].[dbo].[table] AS so
    GROUP BY
        [so].[OrderGroup], [so].OtherReferenceFour
)
SELECT
    did.*, so.*
FROM
    did
LEFT JOIN
    so ON so.container = did.Container 
       AND so.warehousesku = did.warehouessku
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*consolidation*"? It will be helpful to [edit] your question to include the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking questions like this it's helpful to provide DDL/DML:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (InvoiceQTY DECIMAL(8,4), CreateDate DATETIME, Container VARCHAR(11), WarehouseSKU INT, AllocatedQTY INT);
INSERT INTO @Table (InvoiceQTY, CreateDate, Container, WarehouseSKU, AllocatedQty) VALUES
(553, '2022-01-18 11:23:47.887', 'WHSU5629420', 535446, 561),
(8,   '2022-01-18 11:23:47.907', 'WHSU5629420', 535446, 561),
(375, '2022-01-18 11:23:47.903', 'WHSU5629420', 535738, 375);
```

Using this example data (take from your image, please don't post images of data or code, they are not helpful - [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)):

```
SELECT SUM(InvoiceQTY) AS InvoiceQTY, CAST(CreateDate AS DATE) AS CreateDate, Container, WarehouseSKU, SUM(AllocatedQTY) AS AllocatedQTY
  FROM @Table
 GROUP BY CAST(CreateDate AS DATE), Container, WarehouseSKU;
```

Here we're just converting the **CreateDate** `DATETIME` value into `DATE` and using it along with the **WarehouseSKU** and Container columns to aggregate on.

| InvoiceQTY | CreateDate | Container | WarehouseSKU | AllocatedQTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 561.0000 | 2022-01-18 | WHSU5629420 | 535446 | 1122 |
| 375.0000 | 2022-01-18 | WHSU5629420 | 535738 | 375 |

You can change how the **CreateDate** column is handled to suit what ever your need is, just remember to also make the change in the `GROUP BY` to match.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick!! also noted regarding the images

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the `CreateDate` grouped by day, then you can combine them all in your common table expression using the `DATENAME` function. That will get them all into a common pattern, e.g. 'YYYYMMDD', that you can group and select from.

Try something like this:

```sql
WITH did AS
( 
    SELECT
        [did].[CustomerLotReference] AS Container,
        [did].[WarehouseSku] AS warehouessku,
        SUM([did].[InvoicedQty]) AS invoiceqty,
        DATENAME(YEAR, [did].[CreateDate]) + DATENAME(MONTH, [did].[CreateDate]) + DATENAME(DAY, [did].[CreateDate]) AS PlainDate
    FROM 
        [server].[dbo].[table] AS did
    WHERE 
        [did].[table] = 'customer'
    GROUP BY 
        [did].[CustomerLotReference],
        [did].[WarehouseSku],
        DATENAME(YEAR, [did].[CreateDate]) + DATENAME(MONTH, [did].[CreateDate]) + DATENAME(DAY, [did].[CreateDate])  
), so AS 
(
    SELECT
        [so].[OrderGroup] AS container,
        [so].OtherReferenceFour AS warehousesku,
        SUM([so].[QtyOrdered]) AS AllocatedQty
    FROM
        [server].[dbo].[table] AS so
    GROUP BY
        [so].[OrderGroup], [so].OtherReferenceFour
)
SELECT
    did.*, so.*
FROM
    did
LEFT JOIN
    so ON so.container = did.Container 
       AND so.warehousesku = did.warehouessku
```